# Is it possible to only update "see more" inside of map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary, slice

I am practicing a project using React.js as a front-end framework to display the products. I tried to filter the product by the product_type. When fetch the data, I use slice() to show 3 products on each category then if the products in the category are more than 3, on click "see more" button and it will show 3 more products.

Is it any way to just show another 3 product in specific category? Now when I click the button, each category is loading 3 more products.

Any and all feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";
import Product from "./Product";

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [productSlice, setProductSlice] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://www.allbirds.com/products.json?limit=50")
      .then((response) => {
        // All products return as an array of product objects
        const { products } = response.data;

        setProducts(products);
      });
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {categories.map((cat, i) => (
          <>
            <div>
              <h5 key={i}>{cat}</h5>

              {products
                .filter((type) => type.product_type === cat)
                .slice(0, productSlice)
                .map((product) => (
                  <Product data={product} />
                ))}
            </div>
            <p>
              Total in {cat} :
              {products.filter((type) => type.product_type === cat).length}
            </p>

            <button
              onClick={() => {
                // console.log("This is",cat);
                products.filter((type) => type.product_type === cat).length >
                  2 && setProductSlice(productSlice + 1);
              }}
            >
              See more
            </button>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>

      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Products.js

```
export default function Product({ data }) {
  

  const { images, title, handle } = data;

  return (
    <div key={handle}>
      <h2>{title.split("-")[0]}</h2>
      <div>
        <img src={images[0].src} style={{ width: "100px" }} alt={handle} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want different number of products displayed in different category, so you may define a state `productSlices` to represent those product counts.

The initial value of `productSlices` will be

```
{
  Shoes: 3,
  Apparel: 3,
  Socks: 3
}
```

and for example when you click button in `Shoes` category, the value of `productSlices.Shoes` becomes 4 and the rest remain 3. And in the map operation you use `productSlices[cat]` to get how many products should displayed in the category.

You can modify your code like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";
import Product from "./Product";

export default function App() {
  const categories = ["Shoes", "Apparel", "Socks"];
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  
  const [productSlices, setProductSlices] = useState(
    categories.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: 3 }), {})
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://www.allbirds.com/products.json?limit=50")
      .then((response) => {
        // All products return as an array of product objects
        const { products } = response.data;

        console.log(products);
        setProducts(products);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {categories.map((cat, i) => (
          <>
            <div>
              <h5 key={i}>{cat}</h5>

              {products
                .filter((type) => type.product_type === cat)
                .slice(0, productSlices[cat])
                .map((product) => (
                  <Product data={product} />
                ))}
            </div>
            <p>
              Total in {cat} :
              {products.filter((type) => type.product_type === cat).length}
            </p>

            <button
              id={cat}
              onClick={() => {
                setProductSlices({
                  ...productSlices,
                  [cat]: productSlices[cat] + 1
                });
              }}
            >
              See more
            </button>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, one suggestion would be to also pass a function to `useState()` to avoid recomputing the initial state on each render: `useState(() => categories.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: 3 }), {}));`

Comment: Thank you so so much!

I also tried to get the categories = ["Shoes", "Apparel", "Socks"]; more dynamic. I used this to get the categories... but it wasn't working. Any suggestions? 
`const categories = [ ...new Set(products.map((product) => product.product_type)) ];`

Comment: @Olivialavie Make `categories` a state and set it in the `useEffect` hook may work. Check out code in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-browser-pwj3v8?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 2):

You need a dedicated function that will work with your data as need. This can be on when data first is loaded after fetched from API or when the button is clicked asking for more data.

It´s  recommended you work with this data before passing it to your components. This way, you will have a more readable/cleaner code by applying separation of concerns, instead of doing all that transformation/logic on the component. Try to keep complex code away from buttons, divs, components, etc

My suggestion:

```
    
     const [products, setProducts] = useState([]); //will contains the remote data
     const [productSlice, setProductSlice] = useState([]); //will contains the current visible slice

     const [sliceStart, setSliceStart] = useState(0);

     const pageSize = 3;

     const updateSlice = useCallback(() => {

          const hasMore = products.length > currentIndex;

          if (hasMore) {

              //here we get the copy from products

               const end = sliceStart + pageSize;
               const nextItems = products.slice(sliceStart, end);

               setProductSlice( old => [...old, ...nextItems]);
           }
     }, [products, sliceStart]);


     useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get("https://www.allbirds.com/products.json?limit=50");

            // All products return as an array of product objects
            const { products } = response.data;

            setProducts(products);
         }


         fetchData().catch(err => console.error(err));

      }, [updateSlice]);

      return (
          <>

              <button
              onClick={() => setSliceStart(prev => prev + pageSize)}>
                  See more
            </button>

          </>
      )
```

hope could help you